# Pass Javascript Array of Objects to C# Codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, json

I am having some problems Posting my Javascript Array of objects to C# Codebehind.  I followed a simple tutorial and thought this would work quite nicely but my C# codebehind breakpoints in `PassThings` is never hit.

I have tried changing the url to "Default.aspx/PassThings" but it still never gets posted to my code behind, the error alert displays "[object object"]

Here is my client side:

**Default.aspx**

Script

```
<script>

    function Save() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var things = [
        { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },
        { id: 2, color: 'blue' },
        { id: 3, color: 'red' }
        ];

                things = JSON.stringify({ 'things': things });

                $.ajax({
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/PassThings',
                    data: things,
                    success: function () {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });

    }

</script>
```

Html

```
<input type="button" value="Pass Things" onclick="JavaScript: Save();">
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

Codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Services;

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void PassThings(List<Thing> things)
    {
        var t = things;
    }

    public class Thing
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to define `PassThings` function web method

Comment: @Satpal I added [WebMethod] above PassThings in the c# codebehind and still no postback break point is hit, I also added [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: try adding ``traditional : true`` property in ajax call

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Had no effect :(

Comment: The failure callback should probably be 'error' instead. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Dan gettings closer thank you.  I now get the error callback that says "[object object]"

Comment: Try console.log(response); instead of the alert. In your development console you should then be able to check out the object's properties.

Comment: Arguments to the error callback are `jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown` btw. So you are currently seeing the jqXHR object. You are probably interested in errorThrown though.

Comment: "Network Error 500: http://localhost:63229/DragPostBack/Default.aspx/PassThings" Is what I get in the console.  But that is indeed the path to my page.  Is it because this is just a normal aspx.cs file. Does it need to be a WebService or WCF Service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `url` pass proper url with page. Suppose the `PassThings` method is in `Default.aspx` page code behind file then you have to pass **url: Default.aspx/PassThings** if the script code is written within the **Default.aspx**.

If script in seperate js file which is in **Scripts** folder, then you have to come back one directory and have to write : **url: ../Default.aspx/PassThings**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var things = [{
        id: 1,
        color: 'yellow'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        color: 'blue'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        color: 'red'
    }];

    things = JSON.stringify({
        'things': things
    });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Default.aspx/PassThings',
        data: things,
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
});
```

and in code behind your method should be decorated with `[WebMethod]` and it should be `public` and `static`:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void PassThings(List<Thing> things)
    {
        var t = things;
    }
```

Comment: ... You are wonderful :) Thank you. Since my method is now static, is there an even easier way to do this with PageMethod?

Comment: no for ajax call we have to make it static and decorated with webmethod, you can use generic handler of asp.net which is of extension **.ashx**

Comment: See this article :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203621/Call-HTTPhandler-from-jQuery-Pass-data-and-retriev